# Not getting correct status code (409) if email exists using Next.js, Mongoose, MongoDb Atlas and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, mongodb-atlas

I am building a login/Register portion of my app. Right now I'm using [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html) to check if an email exists in my collection.

This is my route:

```
var router = require('express').Router()
var UserModel = require('../models/UserModel')
var { body } = require('express-validator');  

router
    .route('/registration')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        console.log(0)
        UserModel.find({}, (err, users) => {
            console.log(1);
            if (err) return res.status(500).send(err)
            console.log(2);
            return res.json(users);
        })
    })
    .post(body('username_email').custom(value => {
        console.log("value ", value);

        console.log(3)
        UserModel.findOne({ 'username_email': value }, (err) => {
            console.log(4);
            if (err) return res.status(409).send(err);

        })

    }), async(req, res, next) => {
        console.log(5)
        try {
            let newUser = new UserModel(req.body);

            let savedUser = await newUser.save();
            console.log(6);
            if (savedUser) return res.redirect('/users/registration?success=true');
            return next(new Error('Failed to save user for unknown reasons'))

        } catch (err) {
            return next(err)
        }

    })

module.exports = router
```

In my component on the front end I have a function in my `fetch` which will  catch the error if there is one.

```
  handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
      console.log('This email exists!')
      throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
  }


  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    var { username, password } = this.state

    var mailFormat = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
    var error = false

    if (!username.match(mailFormat)) {
      this.setState({ usernameError: true })
      error = true
    } else {
      this.setState({ usernameError: false })
    }

    if (password.length <= 8) {
      this.setState({ passwordError: true })
      error = true
    } else {
      this.setState({ passwordError: false })
    }

    console.log(`error ${error}`)
    if (error == false) {
      this.setState({ formError: false, formSuccess: true })
    }


    window.fetch('http://localhost:8016/users/registration', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username_email: username, password: password })
    })
      .then(this.handleErrors)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(`response ${response}`)
        return response.json()
      }).then(function (data) {
        console.log('User created:', data)
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

The `console.log` in the `fetch`, `handleErrors` is being registered in the console, but why isn't the error status a `409` like I indicated.

Closer excerpt of `post` route!

```
.post(body('username_email').custom(value => {
        console.log("value ", value);

        console.log(3)
```

Is this the problem? Node style should have a `error` and callback?

```
        UserModel.findOne({ 'username_email': value }, (err) => {
            console.log(4);
            if (err) return res.status(409).send(err);

        })

    }), async(req, res, next) => {
        console.log(5)
        try {
            let newUser = new UserModel(req.body);

            let savedUser = await newUser.save();
            console.log(6);
            if (savedUser) return res.redirect('/users/registration?success=true');
            return next(new Error('Failed to save user for unknown reasons'))

        } catch (err) {
            return next(err)
        }

    })
```

**UPDATE**

I tried Nick's solution but I get this:

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: development.users index: email_1 dup key: { : null }
    at Function.create (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:43:12)
    at toError (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:149:22)
    at coll.s.topology.insert (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/collection_ops.js:859:39)
    at handler (/Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:1155:22)
    at /Users/antoniopavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:397:18
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
POST /users/registration 500 312.485 ms - 51
^C
```

Two things I am noticing:

I get back `MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: development.users index: email_1 dup key: { : null }`

which is the error from having a duplicate email, but number one where is `E-mail already in use` message in the console from the promise? And two how can I pass the error status `"res.status(409).send(err);"` from the promise?

Comment: Hey, sorry dude. Was out of town this past weekend so I didn't get a chance to respond to your previous question. I went ahead and posted my response as an answer below. I also updated the previous answer on your previous post as well

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that during your validation, you weren't returning the promise since the mongoose call is async. The rest the code ran before your validator was finished. I commented where you were missing the return.

```
router.route('/registration')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        UserModel.find({}, (err, users) => {
            if (err) res.status(500).send(err)
            res.json(users)
        })
    })
    .post(body('username').custom(value => {      
        return UserModel.findOne({ 'email': value }).then(user => { // Return Promise
          if (user) {
              return Promise.reject('E-mail already in use');
          }
        });
    }), async(req, res, next) => {

        try {
            let newUser = new UserModel(req.body)
            let savedUser = await newUser.save(err => {
              if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err })
              return res.json({ success: true })
            })

            if (savedUser) return res.redirect('/users/registration?success=true');
            return next(new Error('Failed to save user for unknown reasons'))
        } catch (err) {
            return next(err)
        }
    })

module.exports = router
```

**UPDATE**

Just read through express-validator docs. I think you would need to validate the errors during the request process

```
var router = require('express').Router()
var UserModel = require('../models/UserModel')
var { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');  

router.route('/registration')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        UserModel.find({}, (err, users) => {
            if (err) res.status(500).send(err)
            res.json(users)
        })
    })
    .post(body('username').custom(value => {      
        return UserModel.findOne({ 'email': value }).then(user => { // Return Promise
          if (user) {
              return Promise.reject('E-mail already in use');
          }
        });
    }), async(req, res, next) => {
        // Checks for errors in validation
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
          return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }

        try {
            let newUser = new UserModel(req.body)
            let savedUser = await newUser.save(err => {
              if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err })
              return res.json({ success: true })
            })

            if (savedUser) return res.redirect('/users/registration?success=true');
            return next(new Error('Failed to save user for unknown reasons'))
        } catch (err) {
            return next(err)
        }
    })

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Thanks Nick! I hear ya, summer is a busy time of year. I just added tan update.

Comment: Updated answer. Just read through express-validator docs. I think you need to handle the validation in the request. Let me know if that works now. Since we are getting to the second portion properly. I think this should resolve your entire issue :)